# Install g++ when having gcc (C only) -- RH6

Tags: rhel, software-installation, gcc

I have a RHEL 6 machine, which came with `gcc` but without `g++`.
The gcc version is 4.4.4 20100726 (this is what I got from `gcc --version`).

How can I get g++ working? Currently, the shell just returns "command not found".

Comment: It's called gcc-c++ in RedHat.

Answer (score 17):

You need to install the gcc-c++ package: `yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: Thank you - but I'm getting "No package gcc-c++ available". What can be the reason?

Comment: Post the results of `rpm -qa | grep gcc`

Comment: @iamsid `rpm -qa | grep gc` for me gives only these packages: `libgcc-4.4.5-6.el6.x86_64`, `gcc-4.4.5-6.el6.x86_64`

Comment: @ArtemAO If your server is not registered on rhn yum will not work.. You'd have to install the version on your cd.