# How do I install g++ on RHEL6?

Tags: rhel

This question seems to have been asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/install-g-when-having-gcc-c-only-rh6) already. My IT department installed the OS so I don't know how to register it properly but I do have root access. Is there a way to get the same packages using the CentOS repositories maybe? I'd also like to install IceWM but without a compiler I can't even build it myself.

Comment: If you come into this Q, one of the duplicate Q's to this actually has a much better answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102354/install-g-on-rhel-6

Answer (score 38):

You should be able to just do `yum install gcc-c++` if the repos are set up.  Give that a try first (you can see what repos are installed with `yum repolist`).